# MySQL not using indexes when fields from different tables are in OR condition

Tags: mysql, join, indexing

Saw this: [Can you use index in mysql using "col1 OR col2"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386917/can-you-use-index-in-mysql-using-col1-or-col2)
but thought I could ask this related question to keep the discussion simple and to the point.

I have two tables: `lists` and `agree_and_disagree_count`.

`lists` table has two `timestamp` fields `modified_on` and `first_publish_date`. Both these fields have their own indexes.

`agree_and_disagree_count` table also has a `timestamp` field `date_created`, which is also indexed.

In the following OR statement on fields in the same table, both the indexes are used.

```
mysql>  EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM lists l
    ->  WHERE (l.modified_on > '2013-01-07 12:50:51' OR
    ->   l.first_publish_date > '2013-01-07 12:50:51')\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: l
         type: index_merge
possible_keys: modifiedon,first_publish_date
          key: modifiedon,first_publish_date
      key_len: 4,9
          ref: NULL
         rows: 2
        Extra: Using sort_union(modifiedon,first_publish_date); Using where
```

However if the fields are from different tables, it looks like the indexes are not used:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM lists l
    -> JOIN agree_and_disagree_count adc ON adc.list_id=l.list_id
    -> WHERE (l.modified_on > '2013-01-07 12:50:51' OR
    -> adc.date_created > '2013-01-07 12:50:51')\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: adc
         type: ALL
possible_keys: list_id_type_id,idx_list_id,idx_date_created
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 5114907
        Extra:
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: l
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,modifiedon
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: adc.list_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
```

Why?

---

I don't know how to type nicely formatted replies in comments, so the following is in response to @Iserni who has been so kind to help me out:

I did the following:

```
use test;

-- create tables
create table lists (
list_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
modified_on TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
first_publish_date DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
primary key (list_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table agree_and_disagree_count (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
list_id int unsigned not null,
date_created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
primary key (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

-- create indices
create index index_modified_on on lists (modified_on);
create index index_first_publish_date on lists (first_publish_date);

create index index_data_created on agree_and_disagree_count (date_created);

-- load data
insert into lists (list_id, modified_on, first_publish_date) values 
(1, now(), now()),
(2, now(), now()),
(3, now(), now());

insert into agree_and_disagree_count (list_id, date_created) values 
(1, now()), (1, now()), (2, now());

-- query
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM lists l JOIN agree_and_disagree_count adc 
ON adc.list_id=l.list_id WHERE (l.modified_on > '2013-01-01 12:50:51'
OR adc.date_created > '2013-01-07 11:50:51');

+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------------------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                    | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                          |
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------------------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | l     | ALL  | PRIMARY,index_modified_on        | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    3 |                                |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | adc   | ALL  | index_data_created,index_list_id | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    3 | Using where; Using join buffer |
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------------------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+

-- create new indexes suggested by Iserni
CREATE INDEX adc_test_ndx ON agree_and_disagree_count (list_id, date_created);
CREATE INDEX l_test_ndx ON lists (list_id, modified_on);

-- query
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM lists l JOIN agree_and_disagree_count adc 
ON adc.list_id=l.list_id WHERE (l.modified_on > '2013-01-01 12:50:51'
OR adc.date_created > '2013-01-07 11:50:51');

+----+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                                 | key          | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                          |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | adc   | index | index_data_created,index_list_id,adc_test_ndx | adc_test_ndx | 8       | NULL |    3 | Using index                    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | l     | ALL   | PRIMARY,index_modified_on,l_test_ndx          | NULL         | NULL    | NULL |    3 | Using where; Using join buffer |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+
```

Looks like full scan still happening?

---

Look at @Iserni's comment below the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the `JOIN` on `list_id` is under way, MySQL has no way to "link" the list identifier with the fields used in the query and saved in the index, for no index contains *both* the ID *and* those fields; and you can't run joins on the indexes.

Try creating these two indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX adc_test_ndx ON agree_and_disagree_count (list_id, date_created);
CREATE INDEX l_test_ndx ON lists (list_id, modified_on);
```

and retry with EXPLAIN. On my system I tried creating two minimal tables with two records each:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM lists l JOIN agree_and_disagree_count adc 
ON adc.list_id=l.list_id WHERE (l.modified_on > '2013-01-01 12:50:51'
OR adc.date_created > '2013-01-07 11:50:51')\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: l
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 2
        Extra:
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: adc
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 2
        Extra: Using where; Using join buffer
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and then:

```
mysql> CREATE INDEX adc_test_ndx ON agree_and_disagree_count (list_id, date_created);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> CREATE INDEX l_test_ndx ON lists (list_id, modified_on);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM lists l JOIN agree_and_disagree_count adc 
ON adc.list_id=l.list_id WHERE (l.modified_on > '2013-01-01 12:50:51'
OR adc.date_created > '2013-01-07 11:50:51')\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: l
         type: index
possible_keys: l_test_ndx
          key: l_test_ndx
      key_len: 9
          ref: NULL
         rows: 2
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: adc
         type: ref
possible_keys: adc_test_ndx
          key: adc_test_ndx
      key_len: 5
          ref: test.l.list_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where; Using index
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

As expected, I now get indexing on both tables.

Can you post the tables' structure and existing indexes or, even better, a SQLFiddle?

Comment: Those indexes did not help. I executed: `CREATE INDEX index_list_id_date_created ON agree_and_disagree_count (list_id, date_created);` and `CREATE INDEX index_list_id_modified_on ON lists (list_id, modified_on);` but still seeing the same output in EXPLAIN.

Comment: It must have to do with your query being asymmetrical - you have only one row from one table, and five millions from the other. How many rows does the query return?

Comment: Yes. The reason is because, with so few records, the cost of retrieving the rows from the database to retrieve the `first_publish_date` field (requested by the `SELECT *`) makes the search on `lists` equivalent to a table scan (there is no advantage in using the index). If you either execute `EXPLAIN SELECT l.list_id, l.modified_on, adc.*` (excluding `first_publish_date`) or modify the `l_test_ndx` index adding `first_publish_date` as last field, you get index on both tables. I did myself because I had *forgotten to add* that field in my test table definition.